# Is it possible to add to items inside a Logic App 'for each' iterator?

Tags: foreach, azure-logic-apps

I see it's only possible to iterate based on the result set from a previous step; that being so, I guess there's no way to add to that result set *within* the for each loop?

I'm using for each, as I need concurrency

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's difficult to add to a set/array inside for each loop. If you want to add item to the array, you just need to use `union()` method. For example, I have a array like this:

[image]

And I want to add item(s) as below screenshot to the array.

[image]

Now we just need to do it like this:

[image]

The expression is: `union(variables('arr'), variables('addItems'))`